# C++: Specify default value of class template argument based on previous argument?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, g++

I have the following forward declaration:

```
template
    < typename Vector
    , typename Scalar = Vector::Scalar >
class RayPlaneHitTest;
```

This works fine with MSVC++ 2010, but G++ rejects it. I think the purpose is self-explanatory. How do I need to modify it s.t. it works with G++?

I've been trying it with G++ 4.6.3.

Comment: forward declaring templates *can* cause a lot of trouble... be careful.

Comment: `Vector::Scalar` is a dependent name. Use `typename Vector::Scalar`.